# How to customise Application Launcher script generated from install4j to stop dependent process started by launcher

Tags: java, macos, unix, install4j

Is there any option to customise start/stop command in .sh file for application launching generated by installer which is created by install4j.

The solution is expected at install4j level.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the launcher wizard, you can define a custom script fragment that is inserted before the Java invocation:

[image]

As of install4j 7, it is not possible to modify the generated script programmatically.